# SQL - naming of ID columns

Tags: database-design, naming-conventions

I've always wondered what are the pros and the cons of these ID naming styles in SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE cache (
id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
PRIMARY KEY(id)
);

CREATE TABLE cache (
cid INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
PRIMARY KEY(id)
);

CREATE TABLE cache (
cache_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
PRIMARY KEY(id)
);
```

Why some developers use "id" in each table, some prefix it with one letter of the table name or with the entire table name along with one underscore?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's all a personal preference. I personally use `Id` simply because I think of each table as its own entity...then when I reference with a key it becomes CustomerId or OrderId depending on the name of the table.

Comment: I use the same approach as Justin, so the queries look like:

Customer.ID   or Order.ID

Comment: Some people like to use natural joins, which won't work with this scheme.  However, as natural joins are are the work of the Devil, any naming convention which makes it harder to use them is probably a good thing.

Comment: IME, this convention falls apart when you have multiple id's (foreign keys for instance) cuz you don't know which the `id` represents.  Data type won't help, so you have to look at the keys to know what is what

Answer (score 12):

Subjective, but I like to use named ids (e.g. customer_id, item_id, etc.)

My reasoning is that if you name your foreign keys consistently it makes joins easier to understand - it's always a.customer_id = b.customer_id.  Otherwise, with complicated queries that use lots of joins, you have a sea of "id" columns and it's not immediately obvious what goes with what.

ETA:

Also, if you are using MySQL, you can use the simpler join syntax, e.g.:

```
FROM customers INNER JOIN orders USING customer_id
```

Comment: Not really an issue if your tables aren't named "a" and "b"; Order.CustomerID = Customer.ID says the same thing and has less redundancy...

Comment: @Chris - true, but when aliasing table names in a large query, things can get messy.  It also serves as a sanity check to ensure that you aren't joining to the wrong table.

Comment: @EricPetroelje I've only had bad experiences with this, as developers tend to use really bad alias names like iis, isi whenever I see this convention in play just to avoid the redundancy this method creates.

Answer (score 3):

The pros of just using 'id' is that you have a uniform field, and it's easy to remember and type.

The pros of prefixing id with the table name is that it can be easier to work with when working with multiple tables frequently.

cid seems like the worst of three options, with none of the benefits of the other two.

Answer (score 3):

> > Native SQL: its best to use something more specific than id so that the humans writing the sql don't always have to prefix with a table alias. By eliminating the need for aliases you can significantly shrink the size of the SQL and eliminate a lot of errors at the same time.

Prefixing, even with a table name, is no more characters than a more specific column name:

```
customer.id
customer_id
```

On different note, since the foreign key column references a table, why not just use the name of the table as the foreign key?

```
table order (
     id        SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
     customer  INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES (customer)
...
```

Then we have:

```
FROM customer INNER JOIN order ON customer.id = order.customer
```

Answer (score 2):

The first decision is 'id' or not, and it is driven by tool that's handling the SQL:

- ORM:  some prefer 'id'
- Native SQL: its best to use something more specific than id so that the humans writing the sql don't always have to prefix with a table alias.  By eliminating the need for aliases you can significantly shrink the size of the SQL and eliminate a lot of errors at the same time.

The second decision, if you're using an ORM that demands 'id', is:

- You can just go with ORM constraints on all column names
- Or you can name the columns for humans, and create a separate view that renames the columns to what the ORM wants.  This is a bit of work, but if you have more than just the ORM looking at the tables (reporting tools, other ORMs, etc) it may be worthwhile.

Or the second decision, if you're not using 'id', is - how to build names in a relational databases:

- You typically don't have case to use - so camelcase, etc don't work
- You want to avoid naming collisions
- You want names to be a little intuitive without knowing the table name
- You want names to be consistently formatted
- So, cid isn't very good.  cache_id is preferable.

Answer (score 1):

Some ORMs work "better" when you name each table's primary key as "id".

Answer (score 1):

As a few other have already pointed out: It's really a personal preference.

I more or less stick to the third approach (table foo will get the id column "foo_id") but cannot really tell you why ;-)

An advantage of the first approch ist that you can rename your table without having to rename your id column to reflect the change. But that's hardly a reason to make it a doctrine.

Answer (score 1):

**Convenience:** 
The first difference is between how a database designer thinks and how a code  developer (programmer) thinks.
A pargrammer thinks that id is a property of an object(here cache object) so it is completely rediculous that one uses

```
cache.cache_id
```

On the other hand for a database developer it makes sense to use cache_id for example when one needs to join tables and uses aliases for tables. Complare these two codes:

```
select c.cache_id, c.name, ci.created_at as cache_date
from cache c 
join cahce_item ci on ci.cache_id = c.cache_id
```

and

```
select c.id as cahce_id, c.name, ci.created_at as cache_date
from cache c 
left join cahce_item ci on c.id = ci.cache_id
```

as the number of tables grows in the select statement, its getting more and more harder to keep track of the aliases and ids in the query.

**Concept:**
Second difference comes from the realtion between object and table. An object is an instance of a class but a table is a collection of rows. Though an instance of a model class can represent a row of a table, by mistake some people consider a class as a representation of a table which is a completely wrong. This is exactly why most of the ORM systems have configurations and developers can map between objects and tables ( e.g. plural name for tables and singular name for objects or tablename_id for pk column and id for object). In my experience, its always **id** when database is generated by ORM and a programmer is in charge.


Therefore, as a databse designer if you have the authority over naming, I suggest use the tablename_id( cache_id) and tell the programmer to handle the naming however they want using the ORM configuration. This way both database developer and programmer are happy:

```
select cahce_id from caches
```

for the database developer and

```
cache.id
```

for the programmer.